# creating a csv file for movie review corpus in python

Tags: python

```
negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

for f in negids:
  with open(fileids=[f], "rb") as infile, open(fileids=[f], 'wb') as outfile:
  in_txt = csv.reader(infile, delimiter = '\t')
  out_csv = csv.writer(outfile)
  out_csv.writerow(in_txt)
```

Can anyone help please i am trying to read each file in neg folder of movie review corpus     and want to insert the complete data of that file as a row in excel sheet

Comment: Any error in above code? What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use csv DictReader.

```
import csv
import json
data = csv.DictReader(open('filename.csv', 'r'))
print data.fieldnames
for each in data:
   row ={}
   # check condition code here
   output.append(row)
print output
```

*add output data into csv file*

Comment: can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

```
directory = raw_input("INPUT Folder:")
output = raw_input("OUTPUT Folder:")

txt_files = os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')

for txt_file in glob.glob(txt_files):
with open(txt_file, "rb") as input_file:
    in_txt = csv.reader(input_file)
    filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(txt_file))[0] + '.csv'

    with open("book.csv", 'wb') as output_file:
        out_csv = csv.writer(output_file)
        out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

i have tried this code it is working but the issue is each text file in the neg folder of the movie review corpus must come as one single row in the csv file(i.e. the neg folder contains thousand file and i want that the new created csv should have thousand rows one row for the complete text of one text file) but this is not happening the last file data is overwriting the previous file data and the last file data is appearing in multiple rows in the csv file

Comment: When you write to file, try using 'a' instead of 'w' to append to a file. 'w' will overwrite. What is the format of the input files?